# trying to get an information from a class but I get a attribute error

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I am new to Python and  I am trying to make pizza order system project. I need to create a superclass called pizza then create subclasses called Klasik and Margherita. In each subclasses I define ingredients and cost. Then when someone orders a pizze I need to get that information. Here is my code:

```
#create superclass
class Pizza(object):
    def _init_(self, description, cost):
        self.description=" "
        self.cost=0
    def get_description(self):
        return self.description
    def get_cost(self):
        return self.cost


#create subclasses

class Klasik(Pizza):
    def _init_(self, description, cost):
      self.description = "Ingredients: cheese, olive, corn"
      self.cost = 60.0

class Margherita(Pizza):
    def _init_(self):
        self.description="Ingredients: tomato, mozarella "
        self.cost = 50.0

pizza = input("Please select 1 or 2")
    if pizza=='1':
        pizza=Klasik()
    elif pizza=='2':
        pizza=Margherita()
    else :
        print("Please choose between: 1 or 2")

pizza_cost = pizza.self.cost()
print("your pizza costs" + pizza_cost)
```

I look for attribute error pages but They are all so complicated. I looked at one of my friends codes who finished this project, we have very similar codes but when I select 1 I get

```
     AttributeError:'Klasik' object has no attribute 'self'
```

Thank you

Comment: `_init_` should be `__init__`, with double underscores.

Comment: And there is no need to access `self` when you already access an instance. It should just be `pizza_cost = pizza.cost`

Comment: I don't know if this is an exercise or a self-project, but there is absolutely no benefit in using a sub-class here. They don't define anything that doesn't already exist in the super class. You might as well just do `margherita = Pizza("Ingredients: tomato, mozarella", 50)`

Comment: There is no point to the superclass in the OP code. No inherited attributes are ever used.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `self` is not an attribute of your class.

If you want to access `pizza_cost`, just access it by writing what follows:

```
pizza_cost = pizza.get_cost()
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use description and cost as parameter, then define the default values first not in the function. Also, you are using pizza as an instance of classes and a variable. This can cause misunderstanding. Cost is an attribute therefore you can access it by pizza.cost notation, not like a function call of pizza.cost().I think this is proper way but you need to improve it :

```
#create superclass
class Pizza(object):
    def _init_(self, description, cost):
        self.description=" "
        self.cost=0
    def get_description(self):
        return self.description
    def get_cost(self):
        return self.cost


#create subclasses

class Klasik(Pizza):
    def __init__(self, description="None", cost=60.0):
        
      self.description = description
      self.cost = cost

class Margherita(Pizza):
    def __init__(self, description="None", cost=50.0):
        
      self.description = description
      self.cost = cost

pizza = input("Please select 1 or 2")

if pizza=='1':
    pizza=Klasik()
elif pizza=='2':
    pizza=Margherita()
else :
    print("Please choose between: 1 or 2")

pizza_cost = pizza.cost
print("your pizza costs " + str(pizza_cost))
```